# How do I uninstall a PWA with related files in Android Chrome browser

Tags: progressive-web-apps

When we install pwa then it will create some cookies as per our requirement and we can use that cookies for some references. After some time when user unintsall the pwa then its necessary that there will be delete the pwa files of cookies and also some local storage data from index db

Comment: Uninstall AND Settings -> Privacy -> Clear browsing Data -> Advanced -> All Time -> Clear Data

Comment: @Mathias How can we achieve this programmatically using angular ?

Answer (score -2):

in android long press icon of app then drag up to the "Remove" on the top center of the screen 
[How do I uninstall a PWA in Android Chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55130804/how-do-i-uninstall-a-pwa-in-android-chrome-browser)

Comment: sorry link seems to be broken